# laravel chat load more pagination

Tags: php, laravel, chat

I have created a laravel chat application using ajax. But didn't get any proper query for chat pagination. I need idea to do this

```
            $data['messages'] = Chat::where(function($q) use($id){
            $q->where('from',auth()->user()->id);
            $q->where('to',$id);
        })->orWhere(function($q) use ($id){
            $q->where('from',$id);
            $q->where('to',auth()->user()->id);
        })->with('user', 'userto')->get();
```

didn't get any code from google.

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple JS lib : https://infinite-scroll.com/
and use the regular pagination which is `->paginate(numberofresultsperpage)`